# Excel: applying criteria in different lists

Tags: excel

All,

Hopefully someone could help me with the following.

Is it possible to get the answer on below question in a single Excel formula, instead of looping through the list of persons or adding additional columns to one of the two? If yes, how?

Thanks for your help!

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: From the example what is your expected outcome? Why is cat 1 Y/N and cat 2 numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the second table is unique you can use this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((SUMIF($D$2:$D$5,$A$2:$A$7,$E$2:$E$5)=1)*($B$2:$B$7="Y"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott, This indeed works. However, when I have more than one criterion for the second list I don't think it is working. I added a screenshot to my original question. Expected answer is 1 (person A, when Cat 3 = '4').

Comment: It is not acceptable to change the question after receiving answers.  This question was answered, and by your own words works for the original question.  You need to mark this as correct and ask a new question, you can reference this one. @Hans

Comment: @Hans but before you do, look at your `()` they are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hans.

You can use this way. For the last option, please be aware that same person is on the same line for both categories.

1. How many persons have Cat 1=Y? Use `=COUNTIF` formula:

[image]

1. How many persons have Cat 2=1? Use `=COUNTIF` formula as well:

[image]

2. How many persons have Cat 1=Y AND Cat 2=1? Use `=COUNTIFS` formula:

[image]

The answer in the last case is 1 (there is only one case with this criteria). I hope it helps.

Comment: This assumes that the same person is on the the same line.  Change B5 to "Y",B4 to "N" and F4 to 1,  It should be 2 and it will remain 1.

Comment: Yes. I did not make that note in my answer. I will edit it. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Thanks. I indeed meant that both criteria should hold for a person, as Scott is referring to.